# Invalid Property Value for RGBA background in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I see this question has been asked twice before, but both solutions had to do with removing spacing. Without any spacing in between `rgba` and `(`, my issue still seems to persist. My CSS code is:

```
background: rbga(255,255,255,.7);
```

I've also tried:

```
background-color: rbga(255,255,255,.7);
```

In Chrome, both of these register as an `Invalid property value`.

However, if I use:

```
background-color: white;
opacity: .7;
```

The above code does work. Any reason why the `rgba` code is not working?

Comment: Check your spelling.

Comment: RBG -> RGB, and it will work

Comment: I'd recommend using an editor with syntax highlighting, so you'll catch these kinds of typos in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with

```
rgba(255,255,255,.7);
```

Your Spelling is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

hello you have typo     `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);`

and you tried `background-color: rBga(255,255,255,.7);`